# $state transition after rejected promise Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I'm using Angular ui-router and have a resolve function set up for one of my states, before the controller is initialized. I retrieve some data, loop through and  match it up the URL stateParam, and if a match is found, resolve the promise to the controller and return that object in the promise. That's all working well.

However, if a match isn't found I simply want to redirect to a different state by rejecting the promise and running `$state.go('state');`

Simply this:

```
deferred.reject();
$state.go('state',{params: 'param'});
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. The controller just hangs, and I get no console errors or anything. Any ideas?

**This question apply to verion 0.xx, many things have changed in version 1.xx**

Comment: Can you provide more code?  Is this within a `$digest` loop?

Comment: Sorry for now being clearer..this is in my app config for $stateProvider, it's in a resolve for one of my states.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

ui-router is supposed to throw a `$stateChangeError` if a route resolve is rejected. You need to watch for this event, and trigger your state transition there.

As per the wiki:

`$stateChangeError` - fired when an error occurs during transition. It's important to note that if you have any errors in your resolve functions (javascript errors, non-existent services, etc) they will not throw traditionally. You must listen for this $stateChangeError event to catch ALL errors.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#wiki-state-change-events

---

As @gustavohenke mentioned in the comments, a good place to put this handler is your app's primary `.run()` function.

Comment: I've tried listening on the $stateChangeError event myself, and never see it triggered, even when I know $q.reject has been called. This leaves the app in the previous state, with no notification, or, in the case of a first load, in an unknown state.

Comment: You need to make sure you are handling `$stateChangeError` in a controller that has been loaded (eg. higher in the hierarchy than your resolve call). If you need to catch the root state, use an `ng-controller` on your html or body tag as a site wide always loaded controller.

Comment: @MattWay even better: use a run block, and listen in the `$rootScope`.

Comment: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events $stateChangeError deprecated, use transition hooks

Answer (score -3):

You're misunderstanding how promises work. `deferred.reject()` simply notifies the `deferred.promise` that it has been rejected.

```
var promise = deferred.promise;

promise.then(
  function (result) { 
    // this function runs if the promise was resolved
  },
  function (result) {
    // this function runs if the promise was rejected
    // this is where you should put $state.go(..)
  }
)
```

Comment: He's asking about how to handle reject on resolve, he know exactly what is promise reject!